# Docker Compose container immediately exited

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I have been having a battle with Docker for the last two days so I really hope someone can help me out. What I would like: one Docker with a running Kafka instance and another Docker with a Python retriever script. I want to have a compose file that will build all three images (Kafka, Zookeeper and Python) and immediately execute my Python file. The problem which I have is that when I docker-compose up, the Kafka and Zookeeper containers are working but the Python container immediately exists. Can someone give me a way such that the Python container keeps running so I can get into the bash?

Command: `docker-compose down && docker-compose -f docker-compose-swarm.yml up -d`

docker-compose-swarm.yml file:

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:latest
    ports:
      - target: 9094
        published: 9094
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    environment:
      HOSTNAME_COMMAND: "docker info | grep ^Name: | cut -d' ' -f 2"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://_{HOSTNAME_COMMAND}:9094
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://:9094
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "rontgen_images"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  python:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerfilePython
```

DockerfilePython:

```
FROM python

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim
RUN pip install requests kafka-python
COPY retriever-openi-kafka.py .

CMD ['python', './retriever-openi-kafka.py']
```

docker ps -a:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                        PORTS                                                NAMES
c1bd71d6720c        wurstmeister/zookeeper      "/bin/sh -c '/usr/sb…"   43 seconds ago      Up 41 seconds                 22/tcp, 2888/tcp, 3888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp   kafkadocker_zookeeper_1
81d4b03f0aa7        kafkadocker_python          "/bin/sh -c '['pytho…"   43 seconds ago      Exited (127) 42 seconds ago                                                        kafkadocker_python_1
44ca9f264340        wurstmeister/kafka:latest   "start-kafka.sh"         43 seconds ago      Up 42 seconds                 0.0.0.0:9094->9094/tcp                               kafkadocker_kafka_1
```

Comment: Could you check your logs? `docker-compose logs` and there should be the reason why it exists.

Comment: @IsabekTashiev kafkadocker_python_1 exited with code 127.

Comment: Okay, could you add this config to your python service in `docker-compose.yml` file? 
`stdin_open: true
 tty: true
`

Comment: Your container exits because its `CMD` finishes. Try `CMD ["/bin/bash"]` to keep it running

Comment: @tgogos I changed the file like you suggested and I think the problem is with my usage of ' instead of ". But the docker-compose up still sees my 'old' code: python_1     | /bin/sh: 1: [python,: not found.

Comment: kafka docker had an issue related to not having enough memory and thus exiting with a 127; I am assuming `$ docker run --rm -it wurstmeister/kafka:latest /bin/bash` works as expected? Can you keep adding more components to this till the issue reproduces?

Comment: You could execute `docker run -ti —-net host python sh` directly. Then try to install packages declared in Dockerfile and copy touch python script within you code as retriever-openi-kafka.py, see what would happen. Please let me know.